# How to use text from text box in Sub statement

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a `file.copy` statement where part of the "path" needs to be whatever is in a text box instead of being hard coded

```
File.Copy("\\NetworkComputer1\mall\Productionx64\productdesigner.cfg", "c:\mall\NetworkComputer1_productdesingner.cfg", True)
```

In the above, I need `NetworkComputer1` to be the value of a specific text box on a form.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Are you using Winforms/WPF/Web?

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, Windows Form

Comment: If you have a look at the textbox properties in the designer, you should see an ID (something like *textBox1*), then you can access that string in the code with *textBox1.Text*

Comment: Look at using [Path.Combine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=netframework-4.8) along with using the `TextBox.Text` property...

Comment: I have tried that earlier and getting error referencing "network path can not be found"?

Comment: `I have tried that earlier and getting error`, what was the error and `tried that`, tried what exactly? Please update your post to include things you have tried and all relevant code that isn't working so we can better assist you.

Comment: Thank you...…. I will start looking into how to use "Path.Combine".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 paths (origin and destination) are just strings.  I personally like to use variables instead of putting the full path in the file.copy because its easy for me to read.

```
Dim FileOrigin as String
Dim FileDestination as String

'adjust the next line based on how the computer name is displayed on the textbox and
'also the name of the textbox itself replacing Textbox1 for the ID of the Textbox.

FileOrigin = "\\" & Textbox1.Text & "\mall\Productionx64\productdesigner.cfg"
FileDestination = "c:\mall\NetworkComputer1_productdesingner.cfg"

File.Copy(FileOrigin, FileDestination, True)
```

Comment: Works like a charm...…..THANK YOU!